# Oracle 12c standard CDB count

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I am using Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit. Can anyone please help me to know that how many numbers of CDB/SID/Instance I can create it with standard edition?

Comment: You should ask it at http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: You can only create a single CDB per instance. Do you mean the number of **PDB** s instead?

Comment: No, I want to know about CDB only. I know that we can create only one PDB within a CDB with oracle standard edition

Comment: Only 1 CDB can be created as CDB refers to the ROOT container to which we can plug-in or create new PDBs. In [Oracle Standard Edition](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/multitenant-wp-12c-1949736.pdf) maximum 1 CDB and 1 PDB is allowed.